# AutoIt and locked screen

Tags: windows, automation, autoit

I have a proprietary software that I use to download some confidential data from the internet, this software is the only way to access that data.

The software opens up with a screen and then I have to click on "download" and the download commences. I would like to download this data late-night (say 0200 Hrs) every night. The downside was that I had to sit in front of the laptop to "click" on the download button.

So, I wrote an AutoIt script to open the software, wait for 30 seconds so that the software finishes the initialisation routine and then "go to" a certain location (co-ordinates) on the screen and execute a "mouseclick()". I then created a "scheduled task" using windows task scheduler to run this autoit executable at 0200 Hrs. Every thing works fine, as expected.

Autoit executable runs well when the user is "active". But if the user is "locked" (i.e. lock screen) then it is stuck in "WinActivate()" waiting for the user to become "Active" and resumes from there on after the user becomes "active". This means the laptop has to be in unlocked mode overnight which is not advisable for security reasons. I then found out  that I could use "ControlClick()" to do the same when the screen is locked.

My problem now is that when I use AutoIt Window Info tool, it does not show the CLASS or any info related to download button when I hover over the download button. So, may be the screen is a flash screen or something else that was intentionally made to make sure that button CLASS was not seen!

An option would be to take a screenshot, find the location and then send the coords to Mouseclick() but that could easily get way more complicated considering different screen resolution on different machines (in case this gets ported to another machine etc etc)

Any suggestions and solutions?

Comment: The Windows GUI behaves erratically when the workstation is locked.  Perhaps you could run the software in a virtual machine, so you could lock only the physical computer and not the virtual one?

Comment: @HarryJohnston, i had not thought of virtual machines. I will try that out. Would AutoIt scripts work seamlessly on VMs?

Comment: Some virtualization products might implicitly lock the virtual workstation if you close the virtual console.  But otherwise, there shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: Try the spy that comes with this library http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/153520-iuiautomation-ms-framework-automate-chrome-ff-ie/ If you can see controls with this, you'll have to use this library to automate the window. I've had many windows I could not automate with AutoIt but worked perfectly when I used this library. If it works let me know and I will add this comment as answer.

Comment: @JosvanEgmond, Will give that a try but I suspect my application screen is flash and its not easy to "see the controls". I will get back to this question/comment in 2-3 weeks time and will certainly update on its progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinActivate() will wait until the user is activated to activate the window and then return and it is a blocking function in this case so avoid it. Keep your VB application in the background, not minimized and remove WinActivate() function. ControlClick doesn't need the window to be active.

This should work with the right handle name and class name:

```
HotKeySet("!{s}", "_exit")
Local $count = 0
Local $handle

While $count < 3
    Sleep(5000)
    $handle = ControlGetHandle("name", "", "[CLASS:ThunderRT6FormDC]")   ;add name as well if there is one
    If $handle Then     ;check if handle exists
        ConsoleWrite("Handle exists" & @LF)
        ControlClick($handle, "", "[CLASS:Classhere]", "left", 1, 191, 115)   ;add a class if exists
    EndIf
    ConsoleWrite("Try: "  & $count & " times" & @LF)
    $count += 1
WEnd

Func _exit()
    ConsoleWrite("Exiting!" & @LF & "Tried: " & $count & @LF)
    Exit
EndFunc
```

The informations you gave me from the autoit info tool arent enough. Use some other tool to get more information.
Spy++ is a great tool. Try it out and come back with more information about the windows handle name and classes.

And again you are giving a few informations about your code. This example should performe a control click but you may have other function besides winactivate that will block your script again

Edit: Added Tesseract OCR UDF: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/89542-tesseract-screen-ocr-udf/

Comment: If you read my question thoroughly, I point out the fact the mouseclick() using "coords" works fine. The problem lies in the fact that "mouseclick()" does not work with "locked" screen and button CLASS is not visible to use the "ControlClick()"

Comment: Is window name visible when locked?
You need to provide more infos then. Post the output of autoit info tool.
There are thousands of way to take handle of a specific window and store it within the script.
Even a memoryread would work. Provide more informations about the window and maybe someone could help you more.

Comment: _Is window name visible when locked?_ I don't know how to view the WinInfo tool when I have my system "locked". If you can let me know of a way how to do it, it will be helpful.

Comment: Below is my WinInfo output
`>>>> Window <<<<
Title: XXXX
Class: ThunderRT6FormDC
Position: 77, 48
Size: 753, 584
Style: 0x16CA0000
ExStyle: 0x00040100
Handle: 0x00070222

>>>> Control <<<<
Class: 
Instance: 
ClassnameNN: 
Name: 
Advanced (Class): 
ID: 
Text: 
Position: 
Size: 
ControlClick Coords: 
Style: 
ExStyle: 
Handle: 

>>>> Mouse <<<<
Position: 558, 314
Cursor ID: 2
Color: 0x2A3847

>>>> StatusBar <<<<

>>>> ToolsBar <<<<

>>>> Visible Text <<<<


>>>> Hidden Text <<<<
X
`

Comment: I tried Spy++ and unfortunately it does not show the button CLASS. it does show the Window-handle but using window-handle is no use as I want to use "ControlClick" in "locked" mode.  If you read my question again, you will see that I have stated explicitly that I was unable to get the BUTTON CLASS and it appears the main screen is a flash screen. Unfortunately, your answer is not an answer. I would recommend you read my question once more, a check what I have previously done successfully and then hopefully you might get understand but until such time we will be going in circles.

Comment: I read your question but as i said you are giving less informations about your code. I dont even know what your code looks like.
If your only problem is to get the handle of the window, which in my opinion it is not the only one, then you have it. Control commands such as controlclick doesn't need both title and controlid.
One of the two would be enough for them to work.
You can get the handle by the title and then perform a controlclick on the window. However you have to calculate your coords correctly.

Comment: And other option is this UDF: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/89542-tesseract-screen-ocr-udf/
A second option is this UDF :
http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/119491-nomadmemoryau3-or-its-replacement/
But i can not know if they will work with pc locked. You will have to try it out by yourself.

Tesseract is the easiest way to go.

Comment: If you want send a copy of the application and i will make it work for you ;)

Comment: Thanks @user2530266, I will give Tesseract a shot. However, I am not too inclined to go down that path, I had previously stated in my question that going the "OCR" way may be the last option. 
Spy++ revealed that there are few "window-handles" that are greyed out and SPy++ does not spit out any information for those (no control id no titles). As I suspected, it certainly is a "Flash screen" without actual "buttons".

Comment: @suer2530266 I would have been really happy to share a copy of the application so that someone could help me out but the problem is it is a proprietary application and not many would know of it nor discuss about it :-).

Comment: you should nominate the UDF comment you made as the answer. Via UDF is the only last resort, in my opinion.